# Concise way to Add virtual property with neighbour count to each result node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, neodash

I'm using NeoDash, and I want to generate a graph report where each node size is weighted by the number of neighbors.

So this count must become a property of the node to be analyzed by NeoDash properly.

Now, after 4 hours, I finally succeeded with the following query, but I'm pretty sure there should be a more elegant and concise way to do the same, right?

```
  MATCH path=(n)-[r]->(c) //n is already from a subset, and here we exclude _events
    WHERE NOT c:_event

WITH collect(distinct n) as listN, collect(distinct c) as listC
  UNWIND listN as n
    MATCH (n)-[r]->(c) WHERE c in listC

WITH listN, listC, n, count(c) as countC
  SET n.counter=countC

WITH collect(n) as listN, listC
  UNWIND listC as c
    MATCH (n)-[r]->(c) WHERE n in listN

WITH c, count(n) as countN, listN
  SET c.counter=countN

WITH collect(c) as listC, listN
  MATCH (n)-[r]->(c)
    WHERE n in listN 
      and c in listC

RETURN n,r,c
```

or is there an apoc shortcut for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below only needs one `MATCH`, and does not need APOC. The [CALL subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) do not return anything, and therefore leave the single outer row as-is.

```
.
.
.
MATCH (n)-[rel]->(:!_event) //n was defined earlier, and here we exclude _events
WITH COLLECT(rel) as rels
CALL {
  WITH rels
  UNWIND rels AS r
  WITH STARTNODE(r) AS n, COUNT(*) AS countC
  SET n.counter = countC
}
CALL {
  WITH rels
  UNWIND rels AS r
  WITH ENDNODE(r) AS c, COUNT(*) AS countN
  SET c.counter = countN
}
UNWIND rels AS r
RETURN STARTNODE(r) AS n, r, ENDNODE(r) AS c
```

Comment: Thanks. I find the COUNT{} more concise. I made an edit to @Finbar's answer but yours converges with mine: it seems like the key of the problem was to use collect® in the first place.

Comment: But I believe using 2 `COUNT` subqueries requires scanning the same relationships twice, and is therefore probably less performant. You should test both approaches.

Comment: You're probably right, but you also `UNWIND` twice. isn't that similar in terms of computation time?

Comment: No, performing an extra search through the DB is generally much more expensive than just doing processing with what you already have in memory from a prior search. You always want to minimize DB hits.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I guess I want to compare with the original answer with the `distinct` collection. I'm now wondering whether two `CALL` in a row are called in parallel or still sequentially? Having CALL as a parallel keyword would be a serious advantage here, I guess.

Comment: Running the above `CALL` subqueries in parallel is not supported directly in Cypher, but may be possible with some clever usage of [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/). Deadlocks should not be a concern in this use case (as long as `n` and `c` nodes do not overlap). It should probably be a new question, though, if you want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `COUNT` subquery (available since Neo4j 5.3) to inline the count of neighbours to the `SET` clause.

This example is equivalent to the initial query, minus returning the original graph:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(c:!_event)
WITH collect(DISTINCT n) + collect(DISTINCT c) AS ncs, collect(r) AS rs
UNWIND ncs AS nc
SET nc.counter = COUNT { (nc)-[r WHERE r IN rs]-() }
```

The `COUNT` subquery does mean DB hits. As an alternative, you can avoid subsequent DB hits by just counting the relationships in the first `MATCH`:

```
MATCH (n:A)-->(c:!_event)
WITH collect(n) + collect(c) AS ncs
UNWIND ncs AS nc
WITH nc, count(*) AS counter
SET nc.counter = counter
```

Comment: Awesome! Super elegant. Now how do I get the neighbor counts for n and c only in the subgraph that is created using n-[r]->c ?

Comment: OK I missed that aspect of the question. I will update.

Comment: BTW, `startNode` and `endNode` will lead to DB hits anyway, so you would have to test it out to see how performance compares to `COUNT {}`. Running with `PROFILE` will confirm that. _IF_ performance is a concern, of course ...